# Turn off navigation drawer arrow animation

Tags: java, android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, android-view

I've implemented the Navigation drawer which matches the parent height. Now I think the back arrow button that shows after clicking the hamburger drawer button is actually necessary here since I can't click on it as my navigation drawer also surpasses the toolbar once it's shown.

[image]

I don't actually want that button animation, so how can I make the hamburger drawer button stay without it transforming to back arrow? I need the code and explanations. Thanks!

**NavigationView**

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"/>
```

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        // Drawer
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, R.string.navigation_open, R.string.navigation_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
}
```

Comment: Hey, I have the same setup for my DrawerLayout and can't get the Hamburger button rotated to arrow. Any ideas or suggestions, how to fix that? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

On Google IO 2017 this API was introduced, which is available from support library version 25.3.0.

```
    // Install drawer toggle
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
                         R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);

    // Disable animation
    drawerToggle.setDrawerSlideAnimationEnabled(false);
```

This will make the drawer arrow not to be animated.

[See video](https://youtu.be/V6-roIeNUY0?t=2068) at exact minute.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! i saw this on the google IO video, but i couldn't find the API for it or the video where they talked about it haha

Answer (score 0):

In your layout where Drawer Layout is there, have a android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar over their and inside toolbar put a ImageView at left and onclicking that imageview check if drawer is open, then close it and vice-versa.

Like this :

```
            if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
              drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
```